# How to edit python include path

Tags: python, path, include, python-3.2

I am trying to get the python-connect-mysql module to run, but when I execute `python setup.py install` on my command shell, I receive the following error:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-2259.write-test'

```
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

I have Python 3.2 installed and need to install to /Library/Python/3.2/site-packages/

I have looked through many solutions, but do not understand the command shell very well. I tried the following to edit my bash_profile and received an error saying the file didn't exist:
`sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`

Then I tried: `touch ~/.bash_profile` but didn't know what to do once I got there--the blog I read had very sketchy instructions--so I hit exit and it logged me out. 
This seems to be the biggest hurdle for me to download third party packages. I tried the `sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app...` method again to see if the terminal would let me open up the bash_profile since I had touched it and received an error message that I do not have permission to open the file. Can someone please help? I am going crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `sudo` is a possibility, you should always use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to manage your python modules in case somebody decides to replace `setup.py` with some kind of malicious code (and seriously, who looks at the code of setup.py everytime when installing a new module) that giving root rights to execute wouldn't exactly benefit your system.

Comment: I have virtualenv--I was using it to run DJANGO and learn about php--do I just open virtualenv and run the setup?

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is to create your virtualenv and then install the module with the tools virtualenv provides you (check the `bin` folder that will be created for that), for example, create a virtualenv using `virtualenv ~/.virt` (assuming you want to put virtualenv in `.virt`), then install packages with `~/.virt/bin/python setup.py install` or other handy things we all love like `~/.virt/bin/pip install django`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Python **3** executable with elevated rights:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

The path **/Library/Python/*** is used to store python modules available for all your system globally, and these directories are created from **root** user, that's why you get the "permission denied" error. Just use sudo.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Also you may have a look at [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Comment: I have virtualenv installed on my machine, what would be the proper use of it with python module installations? Would I just run the sudo python setup.py install on after I start virtualenv?

Comment: No, with virtualenv you can create a sandbox in any directory and install python modules in this dir without sudo. Just read breaf tutorial on vitrualenv.